# Superpowered SDK sound glitch before every playback

Tags: c++, superpowered

I tried using superpowered audio sdk for my media playback app but i keep getting audio glitches consuming much memory. I delete the SuperpoweredAdvanceAudioPlayer at the EOF and create a new instance of it which opens a new media path but this glitch persists. Thanks in advance.

```
if (event == SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_EOF) {

delete playerB;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this error too. Delete the SuperpoweredAudioIO instance also before deleting the player's instance at the EOF. This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the audio I/O instance periodically calling your player's process() method, then deleting the player before stopping or deleting the audio I/O results in access to memory garbage.